# How does R's iml package handle syntactically invalid factor levels?

Tags: r, r-caret, names, iml

I'm using the `iml` package to derive ALE values from a `caret` trained `rf` model. In classification tasks where the levels of the dependent variable have syntactically invalid string values this can cause issues as under the hood these levels end up as column names during prediction.

Here is a silly example which will throw an *undefined columns selected* error with the last line of code:

```
# ----- Packages -----
library(randomForest)
library(caret)
library(iml)

# ----- Dummy Data -----
One <- as.factor(sample(c("1", "0"), size = 250, replace = TRUE))
Two <- as.factor(sample(make.names(c("1", "0")), size = 250, replace = TRUE))
Three <- as.factor(sample(c("A-1_x", "B-0_y", "1 C-$_3.5"), size = 250, replace = TRUE))
Four <- as.factor(sample(make.names(c("A-1_x", "B-0_y", "1 C-$_3.5")), size = 250, replace = TRUE))
df <- cbind.data.frame(One, Two, Three, Four)

# ----- Modelling + IML for syntactically invalid levels from "Three" -----
ALE.ClassOfInterest <- "1 C-$_3.5"
TrainData <- cbind.data.frame(One, Two, Four)
rf <- caret::train(TrainData, Three, method = "rf", tuneLength = 3, trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
Pred <- Predictor$new(rf, data=df, class=ALE.ClassOfInterest)
FE3 <- FeatureEffects$new(Pred, features=names(df), method="ale")$results
```

I had some examples where a very simple modifcation did the trick, simply calling make.names in the 2nd last line of code like so:

```
Pred <- Predictor$new(rf, data=df, class=make.names(ALE.ClassOfInterest))
```

However, in the above example this does not help and the only solution I found is to use `make.names` at the very beginning to turn all levels into syntactically valid strings before even training the model (see column "Four"). However, I'd like to stick to the original strings for various reasons and I have noted that other equally invalid levels like "0", "1" (see column "One") don't require any workarounds and this works:

```
# ----- Modelling + IML for syntactically invalid levels from "One" -----
ALE.ClassOfInterest <- "1"
TrainData <- cbind.data.frame(Two, Three, Four)
rf <- caret::train(TrainData, One, method = "rf", tuneLength = 3, trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
Pred <- Predictor$new(rf, data=df, class=ALE.ClassOfInterest)
FE1 <- FeatureEffects$new(Pred, features=names(df), method="ale")$results
```

Does anyone know what is happening under the hood if it is not a plain `make.names` or can suggest a solution which let's me stick to the original factor levels in the model?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: This sounds more like a clarification or feature-request for the author, I suggest opening a new [issue](https://github.com/christophM/iml/issues) for the author. (I don't know what you can get, though: the package is 2 years un-updated with outstanding issues, and a recent [iml/w12](https://github.com/christophM/iml/issues/212) asks if the package is still maintained, currently no answer from the author.)

Comment: Thanks for this proposal, I've checked the github link you shared and there is already an [issue for it](https://github.com/christophM/iml/issues/195). So feel free to make your comment an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a feature/bug already identified to the package author in issue [iml/195](https://github.com/christophM/iml/issues/195). I'm not optimistic for a quick fix, since *that* issue was identified in July 2022 (20 months ago as of writing this answer) with no commentary from the author. (The last change to R functions was in April 2022, it does not appear to get many updates.)

Comment: Thanks again for this hint, I'm not really active on github and didn't even think of checking there. But I agree with your expectation of not getting a fix so I will go ahead and paste my workaround as and additional answer below just in case anyone else runs into the same issue (like the person who filed issue 195)

Comment: When I hear about problems with a package, the first thing I try to do is get a feel for how active the authors/devs are. Many (most?) are on GH, and most of those advertise the repo in the `DESCRIPTIONS` file, so it's not hard to find. Often there's an existing issue pointing to a similar question, sometimes with either a workaround or a clear identification of a misunderstanding or assumption. So yes, GH (and GitLab) are first hits for me when researching some problems, especially with packages I don't use and/or never heard of. Glad you have a workaround, as kludgy as it may feel.

Answer (score 2):

For sake of completeness here is a complete example including the workaround I didn't really want to use which shows that:

for syntactically invalid levels like "0" `make.names` within `iml`'s `Predictor$new`is not required and would actually cause an error and instead it just works as if it were syntactically correct

for syntactically invalid levels like "ABC01-01_02::XYZ02-01_2" `make.names` within `iml`'s `Predictor$new` is a valid workaround

for syntactically invalid levels like "1 C-$_3.5" `make.names` within `iml`'s `Predictor$new` is not a valid workaround but doing nothing as for "0" does not work either

creating syntactically valid levels by applying `make.names` before training a model works for all three examples above and does not require any special treatment within `iml`'s `Predictor$new`

```
# Packages
library(randomForest)
library(caret)
library(iml)

# Syntactically Invalid Levels
I1 <- as.factor(sample(c("1", "0"), size = 250, replace = TRUE))
I2 <- as.factor(sample(c("A-1_x", "B-0_y", "1 C-$_3.5"), size = 250, replace = TRUE))
I3 <- as.factor(sample(c("ABC01-01_02", "XYZ02-01_2", "ABC01-01_02::XYZ02-01_2"), size = 250, replace = TRUE))
df.invalid <- cbind.data.frame(I1,I2,I3)

# Syntactically Valid Levels
V1 <- as.factor(sample(make.names(c("1", "0")), size = 250, replace = TRUE))
V2 <- as.factor(sample(make.names(c("A-1_x", "B-0_y", "1 C-$_3.5")), size = 250, replace = TRUE))
V3 <- as.factor(sample(make.names(c("ABC01-01_02", "XYZ02-01_2", "ABC01-01_02::XYZ02-01_2")), size = 250, replace = TRUE))
df.valid <- cbind.data.frame(V1,V2,V3)


# Using df.invalid trying to apply make.names within iml only

# Classification for "1"
ALE.ClassOfInterest <- "1"
TrainData <- cbind.data.frame(I2,I3)
rf <- caret::train(TrainData, I1, method = "rf", tuneLength = 3, trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
# For "1" no make.names is required
Pred <- Predictor$new(rf, data=df.invalid, class=ALE.ClassOfInterest)
FE1 <- FeatureEffects$new(Pred, features=names(df.invalid), method="ale")$results
# For "1" make.names causes an error
#Pred <- Predictor$new(rf, data=df.invalid, class=make.names(ALE.ClassOfInterest))
#FE1 <- FeatureEffects$new(Pred, features=names(df.invalid), method="ale")$results

# Classification for "1 C-$_3.5"
ALE.ClassOfInterest <- "1 C-$_3.5"
TrainData <- cbind.data.frame(I1,I3)
rf <- caret::train(TrainData, I2, method = "rf", tuneLength = 3, trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
# For "1 C-$_3.5" no make.names causes an error
#Pred <- Predictor$new(rf, data=df.invalid, class=ALE.ClassOfInterest)
#FE1 <- FeatureEffects$new(Pred, features=names(df.invalid), method="ale")$results
# For "1 C-$_3.5" make.names also causes an error
Pred <- Predictor$new(rf, data=df.invalid, class=make.names(ALE.ClassOfInterest))
FE1 <- FeatureEffects$new(Pred, features=names(df.invalid), method="ale")$results

# Classification for "ABC01-01_02::XYZ02-01_2"
ALE.ClassOfInterest <- "ABC01-01_02::XYZ02-01_2"
TrainData <- cbind.data.frame(I1,I2)
rf <- caret::train(TrainData, I3, method = "rf", tuneLength = 3, trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
# For "ABC01-01_02::XYZ02-01_2" no make.names causes an error
#Pred <- Predictor$new(rf, data=df.invalid, class=ALE.ClassOfInterest)
#FE1 <- FeatureEffects$new(Pred, features=names(df.invalid), method="ale")$results
# For "ABC01-01_02::XYZ02-01_2" make.names avoids the error
Pred <- Predictor$new(rf, data=df.invalid, class=make.names(ALE.ClassOfInterest))
FE1 <- FeatureEffects$new(Pred, features=names(df.invalid), method="ale")$results


# Using df.valid applying make.names before model training

# Classification for "1"
ALE.ClassOfInterest <- make.names("1")
TrainData <- cbind.data.frame(V2,V3)
rf <- caret::train(TrainData, V1, method = "rf", tuneLength = 3, trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
Pred <- Predictor$new(rf, data=df.valid, class=ALE.ClassOfInterest)
FE1 <- FeatureEffects$new(Pred, features=names(df.valid), method="ale")$results

# Classification for make.names("1 C-$_3.5")
ALE.ClassOfInterest <- make.names("1 C-$_3.5")
TrainData <- cbind.data.frame(V1,V3)
rf <- caret::train(TrainData, V2, method = "rf", tuneLength = 3, trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
Pred <- Predictor$new(rf, data=df.valid, class=ALE.ClassOfInterest)
FE1 <- FeatureEffects$new(Pred, features=names(df.valid), method="ale")$results

# Classification for make.names("ABC01-01_02::XYZ02-01_2")
ALE.ClassOfInterest <- make.names("ABC01-01_02::XYZ02-01_2")
TrainData <- cbind.data.frame(V1,V2)
rf <- caret::train(TrainData, V3, method = "rf", tuneLength = 3, trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
Pred <- Predictor$new(rf, data=df.valid, class=ALE.ClassOfInterest)
FE1 <- FeatureEffects$new(Pred, features=names(df.valid), method="ale")$results
```